# Enable a Tab with Javascript on Vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

So I'm using Vue and Bootstrap-Vue. 
The context:
This is a register page which I have 2 tabs, where when the first tab is completed then you can hit the button and pass to the second tab.
The second one have the 'disabled' attribute, and when I click on my button it should enable the tab.
I tried to do a javascript function, but it doesn't seem to be right.

[My code is on Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r8egqxLp/19/), and also here it is the relevant portion of the code.

```
<b-tabs class = "the-tabs-group" v-model="tabIndex">
    <b-tab title="Primeira Fase" active>
        <div class="form-group row">  
            <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Email:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="email" class="form-control " id="email"  name="email">
            </div>
            <hr>
            <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Senha:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" name="pwd">
            </div>
            <hr>
            <label class= "confirmsenha col-sm-1 col-form-label">Confirmar senha:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="cpwd" name="cpwd">
             </div>
        </div>
    </b-tab>
    <b-tab id="segundaFase" title="Segunda Fase" disabled >
        <div id = "bb">
            <h1>Quase lá!</h1>
            <p>Loren ipsum sit amet,consecteur adisplinig elit.Etiam eget commodo nignbi phometehues</p>
        </div>      
    </b-tab>
</b-tabs>

<div class="next">
    <a>
        <b-btn id="nois" class="btn-link" @click="tabIndex++; enableTab">Próxima Fase</b-btn>
    </a>
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        tabIndex: 0
    },
    methods:{
        enableTab: function(){
        console.log("chamou");
        var tab = document.getElementById("segundaFase");
        tab.removeAttribute('disabled'); }
            }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set a `activeTab` in your component data :

```
data: {
   activeTab: 'tab1',
   name:'',
   email:''
  },
```

then 2 simple methods to set the activetab and return your boolean you will use to render your html :

```
 methods: {
    isActiveTab(tabId){
        return this.activeTab === tabId
    },
    setActiveTab(tabId){
        this.activeTab = tabId
    }
```

..and a computed for your `:disabled` property of your button element

```
computed: {
    formIsComplete(){
    //here you might want to add some more adequate validation rules
    return this.email.length > 0 && this.name.length > 0
    }
  }
```

Html side :

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="tab" v-if="isActiveTab('tab1')">
    <h2>Tab 1:</h2>
    <span> Whatever content you want in tab1</span>
    <input v-model="email" type="email"/><label>Email</label>
    <input v-model="name" type="text"/><label>Name</label

      <button @click="setActiveTab('tab2')" :disabled="!formIsComplete">
          Change tab
      </button>

  </div>

  <div class="tab" v-if="isActiveTab('tab2')">
    <h2>Tab 2:</h2>
    <span> Congrats you made it to Tab2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

See a [simple fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/369318/)

Answer (score 2):

Assign your attribute to a reactive data member

```
<b-tab id="segundaFase" title="Segunda Fase" :disabled=‘disabled’ >


data: {disabled:true}
```

In your click handler, mutate the data

```
onClick(){ this.disabled=!this.disabled}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this option with another way by using the disabled property of a tab
I will introduce some code below and explain

```
<div id="app">

 <b-tabs>

   <b-tab title="first" active>
     <br>I'm the first tab
     <button v-on:click="enableThirdTab">Enable third tab</button>
   </b-tab>

   <b-tab title="second">
      <br>I'm the second tab
   </b-tab>

   <b-tab title="third" v-bind:disabled="tabDisabled">
     <br>Im the third tab
   </b-tab>

 </b-tabs>

</div>




new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:function(){
   return {
     tabDisabled:true
   }
  },
 methods:{
    enableThirdTab:function(){
      this.tabDisabled = false;
   }
 }
```

});

You can use the property `disabled` of the b-tab to enable or disable it programmitcally

So in your data function create a property `tabDisabled` with true as first state and bind it to the tab as v-bind:disabled="tabDisabled"

Then you can have the method in methods:{} enableTab where all you need to do is to set this.tabDisabled = false;